If I use a Google Site along with an Apps Script webapp(set to 'Anyone' access)linked to a Google Sheet, is the email data stored in the Sheet secure?
I am trying to save user emails with subscribe button on a webapp made through Google Apps Script with access to anyone. This webapp has a email form where user enter their email and post request is made from the button.
I want to know if the Google Sheet containing all the emails can be accessed by other users in any way. I want to ensure that the sheet remains private and that no one else can view the emails stored in it.
Below is my doPost() code:
function doPost(e) {
  try { 
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("asbasdsdf...");
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Subscriptions");

    // Check if the sheet exists
    if (!sheet) {
      throw new Error(`The sheet "${sheetName}" does not exist.`);
    }

    // Parse JSON payload
    const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    const email = data.email;
    
    // Check if the email already exists in the specified column
    const range = sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
    const existingEmails = range.getValues().flat();
    if (existingEmails.includes(email)) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(
        JSON.stringify({ status: "error", message: "This email is already subscribed for " + bookCover })
      ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }

    // Format current date and time (DD/MM/YYYY, HH:MM:SS)
    const timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss");

    // Append email and timestamp
    const row = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(email);
    sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(timestamp);

    // Success response
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(
      JSON.stringify({ status: "success", message: "Email saved successfully!" })
    ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

  } catch (error) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(
      JSON.stringify({ status: "error", message: error.message })
    ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}




The question is unclear. What do you mean by "email saved in Sheets is secure"?

Please edit your post and further explain the problem.

Access to the spreadsheet is controlled by its File > Share permissions. The web app will only leak data if you program it to do so. You're not showing much of the web app code, so there's no way to tell whether you've added code there that leaks data.

Side note: you can use sheet.appendRow([email, null, timestamp]) instead of .setValue() to make the operation atomic.

If this is all the code and webapp is published as Access: "Anyone" and Execute as "me", I think it's highly unlikely for the sheet data to get leaked.
